# Query where mySQL table with JSON column in ci's

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter, and I have a list of numbers (e.g. `['1', '2', '12', '42']`) on a column (`tags_json`) of a table names `submit`, and I want to check if the number (e.g. '2') is in `tags_json`, in order to show the data the row's content.

The code I've tried is:

```
$this->db->select('*', FALSE);
$this->db->where("JSON_CONTAINS(tags_json,'[2]'");
$Query = $this->db->get('submit');
echo $Query->num_rows();
```

Result is:

> Error Number: 1064
>       You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
>
> SELECT * FROM `submit` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(tags_json,'[2]' IS NULL
>       Filename: controllers/Home.php
>       Line Number: 281

How is it in CI's?

Comment: try giving parameters null, false as second and third

Comment: You are missing a parenthesis to close the `JSON_CONTAINS()` call. Should be `$this->db->where("JSON_CONTAINS(tags_json,'[2]')");`

Comment: try  `this->db->where("JSON_CONTAINS(tags_json,'[2]')", NULL, FALSE);`

Comment: @GMB i give this error: `Error Number: 1305

FUNCTION grsd1_db.JSON_CONTAINS does not exist

SELECT * FROM 'submit' WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(tags_json,'[2]') IS NULL`

Comment: @DevsiOdedra i give this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in`

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using? If I rember correctly, `JSON_CONTAINS()` was added in 5.7.

Comment: @GMB it is v 5.5, What is the solution with this version (mysql 5.5)?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no equivalent action available in 5.5...

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to your problem. use this code...

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where("JSON_CONTAINS(tags_json, JSON_ARRAY('2'))");
$Query = $this->db->get('submit');
echo $Query->num_rows();
```

it will output **1** and **0** if nothing's found.

if it will give you this **error**

> Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_contains: "Invalid value." at position 1.
>
> SELECT * FROM `submit` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(tags_json, JSON_ARRAY('2'))

it is because your json array is invalid so make sure your to have this format

```
["1", "2", "12", "42"]
```

or you just can have like this `[1, 2, 12, 42]` then call `JSON_ARRAY(2)`

hope that helps.

Comment: i give this error:`Error Number: 1305

FUNCTION grsd1.JSON_CONTAINS does not exist

SELECT * FROM 'submit' WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(tags_json, JSON_ARRAY('2'))` , version of MySQL is 5.5 ,  What is the solution with this version (mysql 5.5)?

Answer (score 0):

Since your server does not support the JSON family of functions `JSON_CONTAINS` you can try a good old `LIKE` statement

```
$this->db->where('tags_json LIKE "%\'2\'%"');
```